# whats wrong with my code that I have to press a button twice before making the triangle appear

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

learning the basics here.
I just want to know how would I have to arrange the code such that the paint method runs at the beginning of the program and not when you click a button.
or am I forgetting something important?
i know that paint method is automatically called when you set the visibility to true but other than that, im not sure.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;


public class Triangle extends JFrame implements ActionListener

{


    private JButton b1 = new JButton ("Blue");

    private JButton b2 = new JButton ("Red");
    private boolean color = true;

    public Triangle()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(b1);
        add(b2);

        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);

        setTitle("Triangle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,400);
        setLocation(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        if(color == true)
        {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawLine(100, 70, 100, 250);
            g.drawLine(100, 250, 400, 250);
            g.drawLine(100,70,400,250);
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawLine(100, 70, 100, 250);
            g.drawLine(100, 250, 400, 250);
            g.drawLine(100,70,400,250);
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
    {
        if(a.getSource() == b2)
        {
            color = true;
            repaint();
        }
        else
        {
            color = false;
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

my paint method was originally like this

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawLine(100, 70, 100, 250);
    g.drawLine(100, 250, 400, 250);
    g.drawLine(100,70,400,250);

    if(color == true)
    {

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    else
    {

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? You will find what is wrong there by yourself :-)

Comment: 1. never set anything's background color from within a paint method. Do that in the constructor or the action listener or both. 2. Never draw directly in a JFrame or in a paint method. Instead draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel or JComponent.

Comment: `learning the basics here.` - then start with the basics by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the tutorial, download the demo code and modify the demo code for a better structured program. Also, painting methods are for painting only. A painting method should NOT set a property of the component (ie, the background).